# Adapter layout screen other devices android

Tags: android, xml, resolution

guys... i have developed my first app... i have tested this, in Galaxy SIII, it's work fine... but if i run my application in a Galaxy SII the TextView is big...

XML layout:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:text="@string/my"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

How do I adjust the resolution automatically with all the screens? 
What is the easiest choice?
I'm confised :|
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sp` units instead of `dp` units for the text, as follows:

```
android:textSize="15sp"
```

From the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP):

> A *dp* is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. **An *sp* is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size** (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).

Also, you can find the differences between these units on [Difference between px, dp, dip and sp in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: Thank you... the problem for the big textview is this?? dp?

Comment: Yes @roxdragon, your text size needs to be in `sp` to have the same resolution on all screen, that's it.

Comment: I had read that you had to create the folder and copy the layout in any folder ... e.g layout-... | layout-xhdpi | layout-large...!??!?!

Comment: Not necessary @roxdragon, e.g: **1-** A portrait with only an image whereas in landscape, you have two images=You need two layouts in `layout` and `layout-land` ([see the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)). Except an image added, all the units are the same. **2-** A text in mdpi with `15sp` whereas in xhdpi it's `20sp`=need to create `values-` folders, add `dimens.xml` on each folder to change units regarding the device ([same for string](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)) but not several `layouts`.